# Singing out of Claims/SharePoint SSO (close browser or not?)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint-2010, claims-based-identity

Here is the scenario:

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4.0 application which uses claims based authentication, using a STS. This is also used to provided a single sign on solution for my SharePont 2010 application as well. The workflow in question is below.

1. User logs into MVC application
2. User navigates to SharePoint (SSO lets them in automatically)
3. User goes back to the MVC application
4. User logs out through MVC application (via the STS  ex. default.aspx?wa=wsignout1.0)

From this point forward the user cannot get into the regular MVC app. However, if they type in the URL to the SharePoint 2010 site they will have access. One route I had was to try to just close the browser upon log out via the MVC app. This would work but I am having issues with FireFox saying `Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.` I tried many solutions out there but none of them would let me make this happen.

I was wondering if anybody could provide some insight into a possible solution?

- Force a SharePoint 2010 log-out from the MVC code without closing the browser?
- Find a way to force Firefox to close the browser anyway?
- Change the way SharePoint reads the Claims provided by the STS?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for not being precise on this one but SharePoint has its own life :).

This is the the powershell I used to solve a similar issue **BUT** you need to have a SharePoint SP Cumulative Update, when I did it I had apply June CU without it session will expired regardless of the user activity:

```
$sts = Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
$sts.LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow = (New-TimeSpan –seconds 1)
$sts.UseSessionCookies = $true
$sts.Update()
iisreset
```

I recall I also tested this version and it worked as well but my SharePoint was a Forms Based Authentication:

```
$sts = Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
$sts.WindowsTokenLifetime = (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 30)
$sts.FormsTokenLifetime = (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 30)
$sts.LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow = (New-Timespan –Minutes 5)
$sts.UseSessionCookies = $true
$sts.Update()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147183(v=office.14).aspx

Hope it helps.